# What's wrong with this .end() function?

Tags: jquery

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/TuxEq/) :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="apri-menu">
    <span>First</span>
    <span style="display:none;">Second</span>
</a>​

$('#apri-menu').click(function () {
    $(this).find('span').first().hide().end().find('span').last().show();
    $('#menu-nascosto').show();
});​
```

clicking on the link I'd aspect to show the second span, but seems that `.end()` make some pain.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `.end()` does is "return the jQuery object to its previous selection state". In your example, the last operation that modifies the matched objects is `.first()`, so `.end()` rewinds time back to just before that -- after `.find('span')`. So the end result is as if you had written

```
$(this).find('span').find('span').last().show();
```

...which will obviously not work because there are no nested `<span>`s in your markup.

Simply getting rid of the second `.find()` will fix things.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below way. The reason is as @Jon said.

```
$(this).find('span:first').hide().end().find('span:last').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/KqdJS/

You can go back to the parent `.end().parent()` and then show it,

You can also see the responses above, hope this helps `:)`

**code**

```
$('#apri-menu').click(function () {
    $(this).find('span').first().hide().end().parent().find('span').last().show();

    $('#menu-nascosto').show();
});​
```